# Глубиной в 543 метра(,) эта яма

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, недопустимая-метка

После *метра* стоит пауза.

`Глубиной в 543 метра(,) эта яма наполнена красновато-коричневой жидкостью, которая выглядит весьма зловеще.`

Нужна запятая? Если да, почему? Ответ на второй вопрос обязателен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Глубиной в 543 метра, эта яма** наполнена красновато-коричневой жидкостью, которая выглядит весьма зловеще.*

Обособление **по ряду признаков**: препозиция определения, наличие согласованного определения "***эта***", выделение и подчеркивание признака (= будучи такой).

**[Розенталь, пункт 1 и 5](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=110#pp110)**

Несогласованные определения, выраженные формами косвенных падежей существительных (чаще с предлогами), обособляются для **выделения** какого-либо признака или для **усиления** выражаемого ими значения.

Comment: Принимаю ответ. А если не выделять интонацией, ставим ли запятую?

Comment: Запятая обязательна. Несогласованное определение в препозиции практически всегда обособляется, а здесь оно еще и отделено от существительного согласованным определением "эта".

Comment: Хорошо, понял. Спасибо!